# disk in use in-spite we perform umount and lsof is empty

Tags: linux, mount, disk, fsck, lsof

we want to perform fsck -f on /dev/sdc but without success

```
    umount -l /var/hadoop/zookeper
    lsof /var/hadoop/zookeeper/

    fsck -f  /dev/sdc
    fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
    e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
    /dev/sdc is in use.
    e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

how it can be

disk isn't mounted 
and from lsof we not get anything

so why we get  /dev/sdc is in use.  ??

```
fsck -nf  /dev/sdc
fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Warning!  /dev/sdc is in use.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (4206042, counted=4212201).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (1310644, counted=1310641).
Fix? no

/dev/sdc: 76/1310720 files (55.3% non-contiguous), 1036838/5242880 blocks
```

.

```
fsck -pvcf  /dev/sdc
fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
/dev/sdc is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting
```

Comment: Does dmesg return anything of significance?

Comment: from dmesg | grep -i error | grep sdc , we not get anything -:(

Comment: The `fsck` program works on filesystems, not on disks.  Add the partition number the filesystem you want to scan is on.  i.e. `fsck -f  /dev/sdc1`

Comment: Are you sure the disk is not mounted? `umount -l` means "Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now, and clean up all references to this filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.". So perhaps the filesystem is still in use by something. Better not to use `-l` so that you're sure the umount does what you think it does. In the meantime, try `lsof -n | grep /var/hadoop/zookeeper`, maybe that'll show something.

Comment: @GracefulRestart It's perfectly acceptable to create a filesystem on the entire disk without bothering to create a partition.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is jbd2 kernel threads. For example:

```
# lsof | grep sdc
jbd2/sdc- 261                           root  cwd       DIR                8,0     4096          2 /
jbd2/sdc- 261                           root  rtd       DIR                8,0     4096          2 /
jbd2/sdc- 261                           root  txt   unknown                                        /proc/261/exe
```

What you can do is remove the disk from fstab so it is never mounted. Reboot. Then those kernel threads will never start.